# Как проверить состояние FSM (машина состояний)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Вкратце нужно проверить состояние FSM = True или False

Если машина работает то True, иначе False

Вот небольшой кусок кода:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state=dialog.count)
async def callback(call, state: FSMContext):
    if call.data == "ctg_instagram_followers_state":
        if state() == True:
            print('1')
        else:
            print('0')
```

Если машинное состояние работает, то должно вывести 1, но проверку не получается сделать, помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Ничего не понял. У вас в декораторе стоит проверка на стейт, значит стейт будет таким в этом хендлере

Comment: Как проверить запущена ли машина состояний?

Comment: Она 100% запущена если сработал хендлер который вы указали в вопросе

Comment: Ошибку выводит 'FSMContext' object is not callable

Comment: Вы вообще читаете что я вам пишу? Уберите к черту свое `if state() == True:...` если вы попали в этот хендлер значит стейт есть

Comment: Ну извините, я не дополнил сообщение, условие нужно проверять в другом хендлере callback, если стейт запущен, то делает "работу 1", иначе делает "работу 2"

Это нужно так как иногда бота приходится выключать и заново запускать, а на моменте возможно какой то пользователь был в стейте и при перезапуске стейт уже не будет в состоянии

Comment: Не спроста же спрашиваю)

Comment: Покажите другой хендлер

Comment: Смог решить проблему))